# The question is this Write a program to prompt the user to enter the number of students, each student’s score and finally displays the highest score

Tags: loops, command, prompt

this was a chapter 4 in c++ program. i need your help to solve this question. the following question is as follows it was in repetition chapter.

#include 
#include

using namespace std;

int main() {
int numStudents;

```
// Prompt the user for the number of students
cout << "Enter the number of students: ";
cin >> numStudents;

// Input validation: Ensure the user enters a valid integer for the number of students
while (cin.fail() || numStudents <= 0) {
    cout << "Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer for the number of students: ";
    cin.clear(); // Clear the input buffer
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Ignore any remaining characters in the input buffer
    cin >> numStudents;
}

// Input scores for each student and find the highest score
double highestScore = -1; // Initialize to a value that cannot be a valid score

for (int i = 1; i <= numStudents; ++i) {
    double score;

    // Prompt the user for the score of each student
    cout << "Enter the score for student " << i << ": ";
    cin >> score;

    // Input validation: Ensure the user enters a valid double for the score
    while (cin.fail() || score < 0) {
        cout << "Invalid input. Please enter a non-negative numeric score: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cin >> score;
    }

    // Update the highest score if necessary
    if (score > highestScore) {
        highestScore = score;
    }
}


cout << "The highest score among the students is: " << highestScore << endl;

return 0;
```

}

it could outputed many student, student score and display student highest score.

i really need to check see if i'm right.